# Steps to use datagrid that will describe database table using objectdataprovider

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

sorry for my English.

Well, Im a student that was made to write a c# project that connects to a db. I havent program on c# before. Now I have WFP program that can connects to my db which is situated on my local MS SQL server.
Now I've got a task:
 I must show my tables using datagrid, objectdataprovider. I have already read some notes about it on different sites. I have already tried to do it. Can you write me here some steps that will help me to show a table according to my task. Can you give me some links to helpful tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you have to store the data you want to display into some collection/list/etc. in your ViewModel or have a method which returns this collection.

Then you use a [ObjectDataProvider](http://adityaswami89.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/objectdataprovider-in-wcf/) to expose this data to your DataGrid.

Place it in the resources and refer to it like so:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource dataProvKey}"/>
```

The final step is to define how your data is going to be displayed in you [DataGrid](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html).

EDIT:

```
namespace ObjectDataProvider
{
    public class MainWindow:Window
    {

    }
    public class DataAccess
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: what does EmpDataTemplate mean in  <DataTemplate x:Key="EmpDataTemplate"> string ? http://adityaswami89.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/objectdataprovider-in-wcf/

Comment: It's just an alias the author has given to the DataTemplate. You can name it whatever you want. It's just to reuse it in the windows body, like so: `<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmpDataTemplate}"/>`

Comment: In your first message.. what does dataProvKey mean. What does it mean? I've got a collecton class, methods to work with collection. "dataProvKey"  is my collection class name?

Comment: No, it's the key of your ObjectDataProvider element: `<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataProvKey">...`

Comment: I have copied c# & XAML code from that lesson and what I found.. Please open the link in the bottom of this comment. Ive got an error. ObjectType="{x:Type data:DataAccess} (there is no DataAccess class in ObjectDataProvider(name of prog) namespace). The see the same error when I adding ObjectDataProvider XAML code to my project. http://rghost.ru/48848527 (WPF project)

Comment: The programm can't find your class DataAccess because it's a nested class (in MainWindow). Place it outside of your MainWindow class and make it public.

Comment: Look at my edit, it has to look like this then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340709.aspx) and this [post](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/438#.UjrJNsakqE0) about ObjectDataProvider.

Comment: I have already read that MSDN post on my native language. But I have some problems in the end of it. When Im trying to add this string  ObjectQuery<Product> products = dataEntities.Products; C# marks it as an error

Answer (score 0):

Here is your basic solution you just have to replace the grid and TextBoxes in the xaml and use a datagrid like this:

http://www.devcurry.com/2011/03/wpf-4-using-objectdataprovider-for.html#.UjrJa5DfqUk