# ObjectDataProvider error. Connecting ObjectDataProvider to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, datagrid

Yesterday I was adviced to see one tutorial. When I tried to compile it C# returned me that there is no DataAccess name in ObjectDataProvider namespace.

```
ObjectType="{x:Type data:DataAccess} // error string
```

My program's name is ObjectDataProvider. I can give you my project. I dont know how let it work.  What shall I correct to run it on MS VS 2012.

**UPDATED (SOLUTION):**

You can find woking code here([C# code](http://imageshack.us/a/img17/8189/ogo2.png) + [XAML code](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/8366/vy2t.png))

Comment: If you're new to C#, please attempt an easier first project. I'd advise you to take a look at the [Visual C# .NET Programming](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html) page on the helpful Home and Learn site.

Comment: Im not correct. I can program Windows form application but I dont know much about XAML coding

Comment: Then I would advise you to look at the [How to create a simple WPF application](http://wpftutorial.net/HelloWPF.html) tutorial instead. (I hope) you wouldn't try to drive a car before learning how to, so why try complex coding before you have learnt about it? My advice would be to learn the basics first.

Comment: @NDGO please wait untill you get an answer in your old thread before opening a new one. Besides, my comment should be enough to solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891143/steps-to-use-datagrid-that-will-describe-database-table-using-objectdataprovider/18891530#comment27917980_18891530#comment-27917980

Comment: Sheridan,there are no objectdataprovider tutorial